# wget vbulletin forum attachments

Tags: wget, vbulletin

I want to download attachments from a vbulletin forum with login. It always gives me an error about unspecified length. In the thread itself only thumbnails are displayed, but i want the full resolution which is in the attachments. I am targeting only the *.jpg, not the rest of the forum.
The url looks something like this: http://www.page.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1234567&d=1234567890
(I think both numbers "attachmentid" and "d" are random and independent from each other.)
When I try mirroring the whole page everything works except the attachments(thumbnails are downloaded).
Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Cheers

PS: Httracker brings me to the same problem, alternative solutions welcome as well :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned about "*download attachments from a vbulletin forum with login*", make sure you have done the login part. So the steps will be as follows.

1) Make the login using wget, and store the cookie into a txt file. Parameter can be *--save-cookies*

2) Now call the attachment download portion using another wget call and use the cookie.txt(of step 1) with this call. The parameter can be *--load-cookies*

More detailed about the wget parameters can be found from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Both attachmentid and Id can not be random at the same time. Otherwise the forum can not recognize at which attachment you are focusing on.